# Increase product image size in Amasty's One Step Checkout Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, image, order-summary, amasty

Amasty put their product image size at 75px in the 'Your Order 'Order Summary area, and mine is displaying at half that due to some css I can't locate.

Please put an item into the cart on their demo site at https://one-step-checkout-m2.magento-demo.amasty.com/checkout/

Is this possible to modify the image size via CSS? Or do I need to override the extension file? I can't seem to locate it either.

Answer (score 0):

You can change mini_cart_product_thumbnail in the view.xml file

[image]